# checking and returning key from associative array if entered data is a key OR value

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I am getting information from a database that I have no control over. The value of "state" is a user entered (and properly cleaned) value, but may be the written out state name or the two letter postal abbreviation. I can easily build an associative array of states and abbreviations. But I was wondering if there is a way, PHP, to determine if a value is in the array of states/abbrev as a **key** OR a **value**. So, if you enter "CA" it sees it is a valid two letter **key** and returns it. If it sees "XY" is NOT a valid **key** then it retuns a default "OTHER" key (ZZ), but if the user entered input is "New York" it will see it is a valid **value** and return the associated key, "NY"?

Comment: and the question is ? *(typing a question mark after a VERY long paragraph doesn't turn it into a question)*

Comment: I didn't downvote your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$userInput; // Your user's input, processed using regex for capitals, etc to match DB values for the strings of the states.
// Otherwise, do your comparisons in the conditions within the loop to control for mismatching capitals, etc.

$output = false;

foreach ($stateArray as $abbreviation => $full) // Variable $stateArray is your list of Abbreviation => State Name pairs.
{
    if ($userInput == $abbreviation || $userInput == $full) // Use (strtolower($userInput) == strtolower($abbreviation) || strtolower($userInput) == strtolower($full)) to change all the comparison values to lowercase.
    // This is one example of processing the strings in a way to ensure some flexibility in the user input.
    // However, whatever processing you need to do is determined by your needs.
    {
        $output = array($abbreviation => $full); // If you want a key => value pair, use this.
        $output = $abbreviation; // If you only want the key, use this instead.
        break;
    }
}

if ($output === false)
{
    $output = array("ZZ" => "OTHER"); // If you want a key => value pair, use this.
    $output = "ZZ"; // If you only want the key, use this instead.
}
```

Edit: I've changed the loop so that it checks user input against abbreviation and full state name in one condition instead of having them separate.

Answer (score 1):

Make an array with states and abbreviations:

```
$array = array("new york" => "ny", "california" => "ca", "florida" => "fl", "illinois" => "il");
```

Checking for input:

```
$input = "nY";
if(strlen($input) == 2) // it's an abbreviation
{
    $input = strtolower($input); // turns "nY" into "ny"
    $state = array_search($input, $array);
    echo $state; // prints "new york"
    echo ucwords($state); // prints "New York"
}

// ----------------------------------------------------//

$input = "nEw YoRk";
if(strlen($input) > 2) // it's a full state name
{
    $input = strtolower($input); // turns "nEw YoRk" into "new york"
    $abbreviation = $array[$input];
    echo $abbreviation; // prints "ny";
    echo strtoupper($abbreviation); // prints "NY"
}
```

Comment: I would suggest one improvement: turning everything to low-case (or upper-case), cause "New York" and "new york" should return the same value. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array("New York" => "NY", 
"California" => "CA", 
"Florida" => "FL", 
"Illinois" => "IL");

$incoming = "New York";

if(  in_array($incoming, $array) || array_key_exists($incoming, $array)){

echo "$incoming is valid";

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!isset($array[$input]))
{
  // swap it
  $temp = array_flip($array);

  if (isset($temp[$input]))
  {
    echo 'Got it as abbreviation!';
  }
  else
  {
    echo 'NO Match';
  }
}
else
{
    echo 'Got it as state!';
}
```

Comment: You've made a syntax error: `echo 'NO Match"` should be `echo 'NO Match'`